# How to implement AutoSave functionality in Web Application(Spring MVC, Hibernate, Angularjs) using ThreadLocal Storage concept

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate, thread-local-storage

I have a web application which is developed using Spring / hibernate / AngularJS.
I have a requirement of Autosaving data so that data cannot be lost. Client suggested to implement ThreadLocal for this. whatever user input on form will be saved in Threadlocal Storage after certain intervals, Once user done with entire form, User will click on Save Button then data will be saved from Thread Local Storage. Even if User closes the Browser data should be retained somewhere and when user will login again the same data will be automatically populate into the form(JSP).

Comment: what's thread local storage? maybe you are referring to browser's localstorage

Comment: No i am talking about browser local storage. I am looking for Threadlocal.

Comment: @sergiu I need to store data in server memory using Thread Local Storage in Java. At the time when user clicks on Final Save Button then data will be saved using Thread Local data in DB.

Comment: @Singh I've same requirement, did you find the solution?

Comment: I implemented this thing using Singleton bean in Spring MVC. I used to store data in map in certain structure.

Comment: @Singh, can you explain how did you save it in the database? what was the form data structure?